# Starting Redis worker from Flask as new thread

Tags: python, flask, redis

I would like to start new Redis workers (as new thread) from a Flask interface.

For this, I have the following function (utils.py):

```
def start_worker():
    listen = ['default']
    redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
    conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)
    with Connection(conn):
        print('STARTING WORKER..')
        worker = Worker(Queue('default'), connection=conn, name='foo2')
        worker.work()
```

and the following call in routes.py:

```
#from threading import Thread #import threading # for starting worker as new thread)
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    form = WorkerForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #w = Thread(target=utils.start_worker)
        #w.daemon = True
        #w.start()
        executor.submit(utils.start_worker)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Now, when I run the function `start_worker()` manually from the console, I see the worker registering.

When calling the function through Flask, I see the comment thrown ("STARTING WORKER.."). But no worker is registering.

Initially, I wanted to start it as normal Thread (commented code), but this results in `ValueError: signal only works in main thread`.

What may I be missing here?
Thanks